# Best Joomla 3 extension to add microformat SEO metadata

Tags: joomla-3.x, joomla-3.3.x, seo, microdata

What is the best Joomla 3.3 extension to effectively manage the structured metadata (microformat) in the pages of a site created with Joomla 3.3.

Currently I'm using JoomSEF 4.5.3, but I'm not completely satisfied for several reasons: 
1) does not allow the automatic management of structured information (microformats)
2) Some behaviors of its caching system does not satisfy me

Thanks to All

Comment: Are you asking about the Meta header tags or microformat markup in the middle of a page?

Comment: My question is on the management of microdata in the contents of the page, not the meta tag headers.

Comment: Ok then J4Schema is the only option I have used and the built in microformats in com_... is being worked on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ITPMeta to crawl and add extra social meta tags

For in article microformat you can use J4Schema which adds a button to JCE editor.

Answer (score 0):

Marcello, to manage structured metadata and microformats you can use Microformats votes for Joomla: http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/clients-a-communities/ratings-a-reviews/microformats-votes  Extension is not only for content, is integrated with many popular Joomla components.

Answer (score 0):

Joomla 3 already includes microformats for core components like com_content, you don't need to do anything to add them.

Comment: You're right, but currently there aren't many possibilities to act on micro data displayed in the pages. For example if I have an home page with no content (composed only of modules) the page will not display any microdata.